# iOS Objective C - Creating UIViews with LongPress / Using multiple gestures on same UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uigesturerecognizer

For an assignment, I must create an app that meets the following criteria:

1. Simulate the elastic collisions of equal-mass balls.
2. Use a root view as arena to bounce the balls.
   a. The root view responds to a long press by placing a new ball. The new ball can be still or with an initial velocity.
   b. The arena should have some friction to slow down any moving ball.
3. Double tapping a ball deletes it
4. You can press to hold a ball, drag to reposition it, and flick it by dragging and releasing it quickly
5. A ball should always be within the arena, i.e., it bounces back when reaching an edge.
6. Balls should not overlap. That is, you implement a reasonably good collision handling.

I believe I have adequately implemented 1, 2b, 5, and 6. If anyone could assist in helping me understand how to implement the rest, that would be great, but right now my main issue is the following:

2a. I want to be able to create a ball by long pressing on the screen. The ball should then appear at the location of the long press. I was able to get this working when there was only one ball and when there were no other gesture recognizers.

Since I implemented the tapGestureRecognzier, the long press recognizer no longer works. My app runs, but shows only a blank screen. No touches of any kind seem to be registered. No balls appear, but the app doesn't show me any errors.

So, I believe that the gesture recognizers are either interfering with each other or are not set up properly.

What I want is for a long press to create a ball, and each subsequent long press will create a different colored ball at the press location. Then a double tap on a ball will remove that ball from the screen so that it no longer interacts with other balls.

Here is the code I've completed so far:

**ViewController.h**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UICollisionBehaviorDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecog;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecog;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDynamicAnimator *anim;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *orangeBall, *blueBall, *redBall, *greenBall, *blackBall;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint ballCenter;
@property (nonatomic) int numOfBalls;

-(void)physics;
-(void)createBall;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Init Variables
    _numOfBalls = 0;

    // Prepare to handle Long Press to create ball object
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecog = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
    self.longPressRecog.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;
    [longPressRecog setDelegate:self];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecog];

    // Handle Double Tap to delete ball
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecog = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
    [tapRecog setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [tapRecog setDelegate:self];
    [self.orangeBall addGestureRecognizer:tapRecog];
    [self.blueBall addGestureRecognizer:tapRecog];
    //[self.redBall addGestureRecognizer:tapRecog];
    //[self.greenBall addGestureRecognizer:tapRecog];
    //[self.blackBall addGestureRecognizer:tapRecog];
}

// Handles Long Presses and creates a ball within the view
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if ([sender isEqual:self.longPressRecog]) {
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            [self createBall];
        }
    }
}

// Set Ball Attributes
- (void)setOrangeBall {
    // Load ball view to screen
    self.orangeBall = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
    self.orangeBall.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0;
    self.orangeBall.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    self.orangeBall.layer.borderColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
    self.orangeBall.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
    //self.ballCenter = position;
    [self.view addSubview:self.orangeBall];

}

- (void)setBlueBall {
    // Load ball view to screen
    self.blueBall = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
    self.blueBall.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0;
    self.blueBall.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.blueBall.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    self.blueBall.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
    //self.ballCenter = position;
    [self.view addSubview:self.blueBall];
}


// Create Balls
- (void)createBall {
    if (_numOfBalls == 0) {
        [self setOrangeBall];
        _numOfBalls += 1;
    } else if (_numOfBalls == 1) {
        [self setBlueBall];
        _numOfBalls += 1;
    }

    // Begin animations
    self.anim = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

    // Init Gravity
    [self physics];
}

// Delete Balls
- (void)deleteBall {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}

// Gravity
- (void)physics {
    // Collision Behavior -- Defines boundaries of view within which the ball must stay. If the ball hits a boundary, it will bounce off it.
    UICollisionBehavior *collisionBehavior = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.orangeBall, self.blueBall, self.redBall, self.greenBall, self.blackBall]];
    collisionBehavior.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;

    [collisionBehavior addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"TopOfView"
                                       fromPoint:CGPointMake(0., -self.view.bounds.size.height)
                                         toPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, -self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [collisionBehavior addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"BottomOfView"
                                       fromPoint:CGPointMake(0., self.view.bounds.size.height)
                                         toPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [collisionBehavior addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"LeftOfView"
                                       fromPoint:CGPointMake(0., -self.view.bounds.size.height)
                                         toPoint:CGPointMake(0., self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [collisionBehavior addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"RightOfView"
                                       fromPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, -self.view.bounds.size.height)
                                         toPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

    collisionBehavior.collisionMode = UICollisionBehaviorModeEverything;
    collisionBehavior.collisionDelegate = self;
    [self.anim addBehavior:collisionBehavior];


    // Ball's physical atributes -- Determines how ball behaves such as its elasticity, amount of friction, collision behavior, etc.
    UIDynamicItemBehavior *ballPhysics = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.orangeBall, self.blueBall, self.redBall, self.greenBall, self.blackBall]];
    ballPhysics.elasticity = 0.80;
    ballPhysics.resistance = 0.50;
    ballPhysics.friction = 0.50;
    ballPhysics.allowsRotation = NO;
    [self.anim addBehavior:ballPhysics];
}

-(void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [self deleteBall];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you are declaring `longPressRecog` with local scope:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecog = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
```

But testing against the class level object, which is a different object:

```
if ([sender isEqual:self.longPressRecog])
```

This test fails.

You can fix this by instantiating your class level object instead of a locally scoped one:

```
self.longPressRecog = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
```

This will lead you to find other issues with your code, but you can see that there is no problem with the gesture recognizer itself.

Comment: That fixed that issue. Now to fix the errors I'm now getting. Using breakpoints, it seems that the UIDynamicAnimator is now causing me to have an NSInvalidArgumentException with [__NSPlaceHolderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]

I don't understand this in this context.